# I want to setup code that handles user and admin roles in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to setup a code that separates user and admin roles in mongodb in nodejs project. when in use admin credentials that should redirect me admin dashboard , when I use it in admin login page and when I user user credentials, it should redirect me to client side page.

help me by sharing the piece of code that can deal with my request

Comment: Welcome to SO, this is not a code writing service. Please show us some code that you have written.

Answer (score 0):

it depends how you design your DB, simple thing is to add type to each user, either user type is admin or subcriber for example.
For each request you can setup middleware or anything else to check what type of user is it and redirect depending on.

Comment: this doesn't work... then while registering every user can fill the form being admin... and then any user can be admin...